# Beginners' Unity3D and Game Design

Tags: android, ios, game-engine

How should I begin learning game development with frameworks like Unity3D or Roar Engine?
I currently only know html/css and a tiny bit of php, e.g. nothing complex.

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: Depends on your interest.
Games can be developed with or without understanding the underlying techniques.

Comment: Also i think the most important advice is to start small. Create something like tictactoe ... no bigger than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

penelop is a very nice tutorial.

Here is the link http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/penelope.html
It is write by JavaScript. If you use C# , you can look at  http://gltovar.com/blog/?p=35.

And also Unity3D's [Documentation](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/) is write very great.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I would have started up with Unity3D, and choosen JavaScript as programming language on it. Because of it is you can find so many resources easily on the Internet. There are so many videos, documents, web sites or something else. I have done like that at least, you know. To be honest, developing game using Unity3D game engine is simple. First, you will add some objects to scene. Second, control the relationship of objects to each other. And after that, you will find 3D models out for your game. In fact, you will search how to develop game for mobile devices. For example searching for touch functions and finally you have games on Google Play or AppStore etc. Just remember Unity3D game engine is multi-platform. That's the point to me. Because I develop a game only one time and I can duplicate it for other platforms, especially to Android OS from Windows.

By the way you said that you just have known html and css, a tiny bit of php. Don't care this situation. Unity3d has an unique structure. That doesn't mean this is easy. I mean that programming in Unity3D is enjoyable only. Just download free trial version and get start it. Good luck.

https://unity3d.com/unity/download

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience with Unity3D and a tiny bit of SIO2. SIO2 is just a framework in C++ without GUI, i.e. yo use your favorite IDE (XCode, Eclipse, ...) and Blender for modelling. This seems to me pretty hard for a beginner.

On the other hand doing C# on Unity should not be that difficult for a PHP programmer. There are a lot of resources, my favourite is a 1 hour [video tutorial by Matthew Campbell](http://vimeo.com/18983027). It is a hands on session and after it you will have simple game on your smartphone, PC or whatever. The [Documentation](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/) from Unity3D themselves is pretty good as well.

Another choice colud be [Unreal](http://www.unrealengine.com/) engine (pretty good reputation), [Bork3D](http://bork3d.com/engine) or [Torque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque_%28game_engine%29)

In general it will take some time to get some knowledge but it's pretty interesting stuff. Be prepared to do some math, especially when going into 3D. Keep in mend that games are strongly related to graphics design, nice thing but not too easy for programmers

Answer (score 1):

My company uses *Unity3D*, and I have found it to be the most successfully-designed engine in terms of combining code and a UI-Editor for developers. In other words, I can code, and then hand of the same project to developers to work with it in the exact same engine it was started in. You can even customize the editor itself to streamline the coding process or give the later team a GUI to work with to edit code, without them having to go into the scripts and know how to do it that way. We also have an *Unreal (UDK)* team, and they love it. It is more similar to Valve's *Hammer/(Source) Engine* and uses a drag-and-drop system called (i believe) *Kismet* for all the coding.

As for coding languages, in Unity we use C#. It is a high-level and streamlined language from the .Net Framework and I have gone from knowing nothing to being pretty advanced in the course of a year. I highly recommend it. Good luck!